# Apex Oracle success with compilation error

Tags: sql, oracle, package, procedure

I am trying to create a body PACKAGE in SQL that contains 3 procedures for adding a customer, removing a customer and listing all customers. But it gives me the ORA-24344 error.

This is my code:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY c_package AS
 --Adds a customer
 PROCEDURE addCustomer(c_id customers.id%type,
 c_name customers.name%type,
 c_age customers.age%type,
 c_addr customers.address%type,
 c_sal customers.salary%type)
 IS
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO customers(id,name,age,address,salary)
   VALUES(c_id,c_name,c_age,c_addr,c_sal);
 END addCustomer;

 --Removes a customer
 PROCEDURE delCutomer(c_id customers.id%TYPE) IS
 BEGIN
  DELETE FROM customers
  WHERE id = c_id;
 END delCustomer;

 --Lists all customers
 PROCEDURE listCustomer IS
 CURSOR c_customers is
  SELECT name FROM customers;
 TYPE c_list is TABLE OF customers.name%type;
 name_list c_list := c_list();
 counter integer := 0;
 BEGIN
  FOR n IN c_customers LOOP
   counter := counter + 1;
   name_list.extend;
   name_list(counter) := n.name;
   dbms_output.put_line('Customer(' ||counter||') '||name_list(counter));
  END LOOP;
 END listCustomer;

END c_package;
```

Comment: If yiou can't see the actual errors any other way, query the `user_errors` view. Two mistakes that jump out are that `END addCustomers` should be `END addCustomer`, and in that insert you've omitted `c_name` from the values clause. There may be other issues as well though. What is the point of populating the `c_list` collection?

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to learn different ways of programming in SQL. Also even though i rewrote the code the problem still remains.

Comment: Your second routine's name is misspelt (`delCutomer`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the PROCEDURE inside the PACKAGE BODY had to be ended with just an "END" not "END procedure_name".

This is the correct code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY c_package AS
 --Adds a customer
 PROCEDURE addCustomer(c_id customers.id%type,
 c_name customers.name%type,
 c_age customers.age%type,
 c_addr customers.address%type,
 c_sal customers.salary%type)
 IS
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO customers(id,name,age,address,salary)
   VALUES(c_id,c_name,c_age,c_addr,c_sal);
 END;

 --Removes a customer
 PROCEDURE delCutomer(c_id customers.id%TYPE) IS
 BEGIN
  DELETE FROM customers
  WHERE id = c_id;
 END;

 --Lists all customers
 PROCEDURE listCustomer IS
 CURSOR c_customers is
  SELECT name FROM customers;
 TYPE c_list is TABLE OF customers.name%type;
 name_list c_list := c_list();
 counter integer := 0;
 BEGIN
  FOR n IN c_customers LOOP
   counter := counter + 1;
   name_list.extend;
   name_list(counter) := n.name;
   dbms_output.put_line('Customer(' ||counter||') '||name_list(counter));
  END LOOP;
 END;

END c_package;
```

Comment: That is not correct. Using `END procedure_name` is fine, and even preferable. As noted in comments on your question, the name has to match though. You have for some reason edited the question to remove some of those errors. This will now compile, but your reason is wrong, and you have still got `delCutomer` instead of `delCustomer`.